# How to use pdfsig from poppler-utils

Tags: ubuntu, poppler

I would like to use pdfsig from poppler-utils in my ubuntu 16.04, at first I installed poppler utils from apt but pdfsig was not part of that package. When I looked man pages for 'pdfinfo' in the SEE ALSO section, according to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/pdfinfo.1.html it should appear pdfsig(1), but in my ubuntu 16.04 there were just a few ones and pdfsig was missing.

I looked for the sources to compile, from https://poppler.freedesktop.org/ I downloaded and compiled poppler-0.65.0.tar.xz. Now when I see the manpages for pdfinfo I can see pdfsig(1) in the SEE ALSO section. But when I try to run pdfsig in command line, nothing happens and a message saying `pdfsig: command not found` appears. Also if I try to look man pages for pdfsig like `man pdfsig` or `man 1 pdfsig`, a message saying `No manual entry pdfsig` or `No manual entry for pdfsig in section 1` appears.

Am I missing something? please if someone knows how to use pdfsig I would really appreciate help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said, "I installed poppler utils from apt but pdfsig was not part of that package." To me, this sounds like a bug, either in Ubuntu 16.04 or in your `apt` configuration or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `pdfsig` is not in the `poppler-utils` that comes with 16.04.  However, it is in `poppler-utils` from 16.10 and later.

If the compile of poopler 0.65 completed successfully, you should be able to run `pdfsig` by giving the path to the compiled binary.  You can probably find the path by running `find . -type f | grep '/pdfsig$'` in the poopler build directory.  Then you just run `./path/to/pdfsig <options> <PDF file>`

Alternatively, you could install the poppler-utils from the 16.10 packages.  You'll need to download the deb files from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/).  Just search for `0.44.0` or `0.48.0` and download the right one for your architecture (probably `i386` or `amd64`, if you're on a 32-bit or 64-bit x86 architecture).  You won't need all the matching packages.  Run `dpkg-query -l |grep poppler` to find the names of the packages you should download.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just used the repos from ubuntu 17.10 in my sources.list, updated and upgraded poppler-utils, now it works!!